# Optimize left join query with multiple counts in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: count, sqlalchemy, left-join, query-optimization, mariadb

Trying to optimize a query, which has multiple counts for objects in subordinate table (used aliases in SQLAlchemy). In Witch Academia terms, something like this:

```
SELECT
  exam.id                AS exam_id,
  exam.name              AS exam_name,
  count(tried_witch.id)  AS tried,
  count(passed_witch.id) AS passed,
  count(failed_witch.id) AS failed
FROM exam
  LEFT OUTER JOIN witch AS tried_witch
    ON tried_witch.exam_id = exam.id AND
       tried_witch.is_failed = 0 AND
       tried_witch.status != "passed"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN witch AS passed_witch
    ON passed_witch.exam_id = exam.id AND
       passed_witch.is_failed = 0 AND
       passed_witch.status = "passed"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN witch AS failed_witch
    ON failed_witch.exam_id = exam.id AND
       failed_witch.is_failed = 1
GROUP BY exam.id, exam.name
ORDER BY tried ASC
LIMIT 20
```

Number of witches can be large (hundreds of thousands), number of exams is lower (hundreds), so the above query is quite slow. In a lot of similar questions I've found answers, which propose the above, but I feel like a totally different approach is needed here. I am stuck at coming up with alternative. NB, there is a need to order by calculated counts. It is also important to have zeros as counts, of course, where due. (do not pay attention to a somewhat funny model: witches can easily clone themselves to go to multiple exams, thus per exam identity)

With one EXISTS subquery, which is not reflected in the above and does not influence the ouotcome, the situation is:

```
# Query_time: 1.135747  Lock_time: 0.000209  Rows_sent: 20  Rows_examined: 98174
# Rows_affected: 0
# Full_scan: Yes  Full_join: No  Tmp_table: Yes  Tmp_table_on_disk: Yes
# Filesort: Yes  Filesort_on_disk: No  Merge_passes: 0  Priority_queue: No
```

Updated query, which is still quite slow:

```
SELECT
  exam.id              AS exam_id,
  exam.name            AS exam_name,
  count(CASE WHEN (witch.status != "passed" AND witch.is_failed = 0)
    THEN witch.id
        ELSE NULL END) AS tried,
  count(CASE WHEN (witch.status = "passed" AND witch.is_failed = 0)
    THEN witch.id
        ELSE NULL END) AS passed,
  count(CASE WHEN (witch.is_failed = 1)
    THEN witch.id
        ELSE NULL END) AS failed
FROM exam
  LEFT OUTER JOIN witch ON witch.exam_id = exam.id
GROUP BY exam.id, exam.name
ORDER BY tried ASC
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Instead of 3 separate joins, have 1 and do conditional counts?

Comment: Still quite slow... It was faster before in "N + 1" query situation. I thought making one query will speed things up. Very strange.

Comment: Is `witch.exam_id` indexed?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Is your "N+1" a proper comparison? Did you limit the result to 20 rows also there? If yes, then that N+1 is 21, while the implied here is quite higher.

Comment: N is of course in hundreds-thousands. How otherwise to sort on the application side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Indexing** is the key to get performance of the query.
I do not know `MariaDB` at all, so not sure what the possibilities are. But if it is anything like `Microsoft SQL Server`, then here is what I would try:

1. Create ONE composite index covering ALL the required columns: `witch_id`, `status` and `is_failed`. If the query uses that index, that should be it. Here the order of the included columns might be very important. Then profile the query in order to understand if the index is used. See [Optimization and Indexes](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/optimization-and-indexes/) documentation page.
2. Consider [Generated (Virtual and Persistent) Columns](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/generated-columns/).
   It looks like all the information for classification of the `witch` into `tried`, `passed` or `failed` bucket is contained in the row for `witch`. Therefore, you can basically create those `virtual` columns on the database table directly and use `PERSISTENT` option. This option allows creating index on it. Then you can create an index specifically for this query containing `witch_id` and three virtual columns: `tried`, `passed` and `failed`. Make sure you query uses it, and that should be pretty good. The query will then look very simple:

   ```
   SELECT      exam.id,
               exam.name,
               sum(witch.tried) AS tried,
               sum(witch.passed) AS passed,
               sum(witch.failed) AS failed
   FROM        exam
   INNER JOIN  witch ON exam.id = witch.exam_id
   GROUP BY    exam.id,
               exam.name 
   ORDER BY    sum(witch.tried)
   LIMIT       20
   ```

Although query simple comparisons and AND/OR clauses, you are basically offloading the calculation of the 3 statuses to the database during INSERT/UPDATE. Then during SELECT you query should be much faster.

*Your example does not specify any result filtering (`WHERE` clause), but if you have one, it might also have an impact on the way one optimises indices for query performance.*

**Original answer:** Below is the originally proposed change to the query.
*Here i assume that indexing part of the optimisation has been already done.*

Could you try with `SUM` instead of `COUNT`?

```
SELECT exam.id,
       exam.name,
       sum(CASE
               WHEN (witch.is_failed = 0
                     AND witch.status != 'passed') THEN 1
               ELSE 0
           END) AS tried,
       sum(CASE
               WHEN (witch.is_failed = 0
                     AND witch.status = 'passed') THEN 1
               ELSE 0
           END) AS passed,
       sum(CASE
               WHEN (witch.is_failed = 1) THEN 1
               ELSE 0
           END) AS failed
FROM exam
INNER JOIN witch ON exam.id = witch.exam_id
GROUP BY exam.id,
         exam.name
ORDER BY sum(CASE
                 WHEN (witch.is_failed = 0
                       AND witch.status != 'passed') THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
             END)
LIMIT 20
```

---

*The rest:*
Given you have specified `sqlalchemy` in your answer, here is the `sqlalchemy` code, which i used to model and generate the query:

```
# model
class Exam(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)


class Witch(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    exam_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('exam.id'))
    is_failed = Column(Integer)
    status = Column(String)

    exam = relationship(Exam, backref='witches')


    # computed fields
    @hybrid_property
    def tried(self):
        return self.is_failed == 0 and self.status != 'passed'

    @hybrid_property
    def passed(self):
        return self.is_failed == 0 and self.status == 'passed'

    @hybrid_property
    def failed(self):
        return self.is_failed == 1


    # computed fields: expression
    @tried.expression
    def _tried_expression(cls):
        return case([(and_(
            cls.is_failed == 0,
            cls.status != 'passed',
        ), 1)], else_=0)

    @passed.expression
    def _passed_expression(cls):
        return case([(and_(
            cls.status == 'passed',
            cls.is_failed == 0,
        ), 1)], else_=0)

    @failed.expression
    def _failed_expression(cls):
        return case([(cls.is_failed == 1, 1)], else_=0)
```

and:

```
# query
q = (
    session.query(
        Exam.id, Exam.name,
        func.sum(Witch.tried).label("tried"),
        func.sum(Witch.passed).label("passed"),
        func.sum(Witch.failed).label("failed"),
    )
    .join(Witch)
    .group_by(Exam.id, Exam.name)
    .order_by(func.sum(Witch.tried))
    .limit(20)
)
```

Comment: In inlined sum in the ORDER BY essential? Also, will this cover zero sums? (due to changing LEFT OUTER JOIN to INNER JOIN)

Comment: In _this_ formulation, `LEFT` matters only if there are no rows in `witch`.  If `is_failed` or `status` can be `NULL`, there there is a problem.

Comment: `SUM(CASE WHEN expr THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` can be shortened to `SUM(expr)`.

Comment: Interesting: When I write the abbreviated `SUM` in SQLAlchemy 0.9.7, `query.all()` fails: `ValueError: int_to_boolean only accepts None, 0 or 1`. However, when I write the same query with `SUM-CASE`, the only hassle is converting `Decimal` to int afterwards.

Comment: Resulting query is a bit better, but can more be achieved by indexing `status`? There are only about 10 statuses.

Comment: @RomanSusi: will comment on indexing in the answer itself (needs more space)

Comment: Is `failed` a boolean/bit or can it have more than two non-NULL values?

Comment: Boolean (`tinyint(1)`).

Comment: Also, is it essential that `ORDER BY` repeats expression? Why `AS somelabel` can't be used?

Comment: @RomanSusi: i do not think it is essential. Again, I generated this query using the `sqlalchemy` model, so there it is. But also not all databases support ordering or grouping by referencing the resulting column, but if MariaDB does - great. I would also think that DB execution engines are smart enough to optimise it so the calculation is really not done twice, and would be very surprised if this is not the case.

Comment: Thank you for accepting the answer, but it would be great to learn what have you done and how your result improved. Thank you!

Comment: I accepted because I cant do the check in bounty 5 days frame. The original answer improved the result: query became under second from 1.1 s it used to be (no more in the slow queries log!). Also regarding the WHERE clause - yes, there is one, but alone it does not affect the query (I've tried by removing it). Also, the query never appeared in the queries without indexes log (if that matters). And last not least - this technique (composite index plus "cached"/computed values) is new to my arsenal, thanks! I will definitely benchmark it as soon as I can.

Comment: I am very sorry I still have not checked this due to slipped business case. However, there seem to be similar cases on the horizon, where sum/case/hybrid properties can be used similarly, so I am keeping this answer in mind all the time.